# Oracle sql: is there a way to compose queries using aliases for entire clauses?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Analyzing an Oracle DB of an application of mine, I always run queries ending with the very same "order by" clause, given that every table has a date type "DT_EXTRACTION" column.

Is there a way to define an alias for String "order by DT_EXTRACTION desc" (say, equals to $DD) and write my query like this?

```
select *
from foo
$DD;
```

Comment: I'm only aware of that being possible with dynamically executed SQL - are you looking for a non-dynamic way?

Comment: I'm running queries from Oracle SQL developer, not in PL/SQL procedures or functions

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using SQL Developer you could (ab)use substitution variables for this:

```
define DD='order by DT_EXTRACTION desc'

select * from your_table
&DD;
```

but you'd have to either `define` that string in each script/session, or add it to a login script to make it always available (which you can choose from Tools->Preferences->Database).

That would work in SQL*Plus too.

SQL Developer also has 'snippets', which you can view and manage from the panel revealed by View->Snippets. You can add your own snippet for that `order by` clause, and can then drag-and-drop it from the snippets panel into your code wherever you need to use it. Not quite what you asked for but still useful. [@thatjeffsmith has a write up with pictures](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/08/i-say-snippet-snippet-good-sql-developer-snippets/), so I won't repeat those details here, since it's not quite what you need.

You may find [code templates](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/11/sql-editor-code-templates-a-must-know-trick/) useful too. From Tool->Preferences->Database choose SQL Editor Code Templates, and define a new one for your string:

[image]

Then in the worksheet, type as far as:

```
select * from your_table DD
```

hit control-space and it will expand automatically to

```
select * from your_table order by dt_extraction desc
```